# Display menu item to anonymous user even when access permission is set to authenticated users

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-9

I have create a page through view and set the access permission as authenticated users

i have added the page link to the menu. Now the menu link is visible  to only authenticated user as expected

My requirement is
i want to show the menu link to anonymous users too, so the user can click the link and see the page content(Access denied message).

Im using Drupal 9 version. I have tried using Menu Items Visibility, and Menu Item Visibility, but no luck

Is there any way to do this either through hook or any contributed modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this module for menu link access:
https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_role_access

This is work for me

steps:
1)install module
2)add separate link for only anonymous user which is not display in any other role and add link path for access denied page